# The method setChecked(boolean) is undefined

Tags: android, checkbox, boolean, sharedpreferences

Could you help me with my application? Could you rewrite my code please? Eclipse show me these problems:

-The method setChecked(boolean) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

-The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){}) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

-The method putBoolean(String, boolean) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

My code:

```
    package com.example.actionoverflow;

    import com.example.actionoverflow.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;

    public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

        SharedPreferences checkBoxDummy;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        checkBoxDummy.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkBoxDummy", false));

        checkBoxDummy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

        SharedPreferences.putBoolean("checkBoxDummy", isChecked);
            }
        });



    }
    }
```

Comment: SharedPreferences in not a View. You can't use those methods on it. 
See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code *for* you? No. I can definitely help though.

> The method setChecked(boolean) is undefined for the type
>   SharedPreferences

`checkBoxDummy` is of type [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), so it doesn't have a `setChecked()` method.

> The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
>   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){}) is undefined for the type
>   SharedPreferences

`checkBoxDummy` is of type [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), so it doesn't have a `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method.

> The method putBoolean(String, boolean) is undefined for the type
>   SharedPreferences

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) doesn't have a `putBoolean()` method.

---

I'm not convinced you've really read any documentation or tutorials on this.

You seem to be wanting to do something like:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("key", 1);
editor.putBoolean("key", true);
```

Combined with the use of (maybe) a [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html).

Hopefully this gives you a bit more reference to continue.